# Possible namespace errors in OpenCV header files

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm just now getting into OpenCV (4.1.0) in C++ (relatively new to both) and I'm getting an odd error from simply including some header files. (GCC 6.3.0)

Error:

```
                 from c:\Users\Logan\Projects\Code\C++\webcamTest.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Logan\Projects\Code\C++\Includes\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:697:14: error: 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Logan\Projects\Code\C++\Includes\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:25: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                         ^~
C:\Users\Logan\Projects\Code\C++\Includes\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:25: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
C:\Users\Logan\Projects\Code\C++\Includes\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
```

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

To me this looks like an error with the way the headers are set up, but perhaps I didn't set something up correctly?

Currently the command I'm using is as follows:
`g++ -std=c++11 -g -I C:\\Users\\Logan\\Projects\\Code\\C++\\Includes\\opencv\\build\\include -o C:\\Users\\Logan\\Projects\\Code\\C++\\Bins\\<File name I'm using in the editor>.exe <File I'm using in the editor>`

Comment: All of the errors are the result of `recursive_mutex` not being found. Are you building to C++11 or better?

Comment: @user4581301 I'm very new to C++ so I'm not sure what are considered parts of the C++11-14 standards.

Comment: @Pip *always* use C++11 or greater if you can. Most libraries this days require it. On gcc and clang you should add `-std=c++11` on your command line.

Comment: @Mirko I added the argument but the error hasn't changed.

Comment: To be sure about the version you're using, you can do: https://ideone.com/Is9yqf if it says 199711 or something like that, you should look at your compiler options. If it say's anything bigger or equal than 201103, that's not the problem.

Comment: Recommend adding your compiler and compiler version to the question. Some of the early C++11 implementations still in wide use are lacking. Sometimes trickier details are broken or incomplete and not supported.

Comment: @user4581301 Fair, adding now.

Comment: @Mirko The output was 201103, but the tooltip in VSCode says it's #defined as 199711. https://imgur.com/QmHcxeC

Comment: @Pip That means your compiler is working with C++11, but your IDE isn't. It will only make the IDE say that it doesn't know things like `std::recursive_mutex`, but that's *not* the problem with the compiler.

Comment: IDE variable peeking is often fooled by conditional compilation. In this case VS code probably doesn't know that the command line is changing the C++ Standard and is assuming (Zoinks!) C++98. C++ support in GCC 6.3 is [pretty damn solid](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/projects/cxx-status.html). Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: OpenCV 4.x requires C++11. Details [here](https://opencv.org/opencv-4-0/)

Comment: Can you add the compiler command line generated and used by VS Code?

Comment: @user4581301 Added.

Comment: There's no `-std-c++11` in that command line.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, thanks, just forgot to add it there. I have been using it.